# Visual Studio 2017 - Changing values of an instance of a class acting weird

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017, C#

So I have a class that stores data in multiple two or three dimensional arrays from another method. However, when I actually modify one of the values (and only one of the values), modifying any other values within the instance of the class also modify that value. Nothing is static, and nothing happens between when one value is modified and when another is modified.

The class;

```
public class TestResults
{
    public int finalResult;
    public float[,] activations;
    public float[,] magnitudes;
    public float[, ,] weights;
    public float[,] biases;
    public int actual;

    public TestResults(int newF, float[,] newAct, float[,] newMag, float[, ,] newW, float[,] newB, int newA)
    {
        finalResult = newF;
        activations = newAct;
        magnitudes = newMag;
        weights = newW;
        biases = newB;
        actual = newA;
    }
}
```

The problematic script (

```
for (int l = 1; l < 4; l++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeCounts[l]; i++)
                {
                    float newValue = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < nodeCounts[l - 1]; j++)
                    {
                        float inputValue = nodes[l - 1, j].value;
                        float newMag = (inputValue * nodes[l, i].weights[j]);

                        newValue += newMag;

                        //Update test results
                        result.weights[l, i, j] = nodes[l, i].weights[j];
                    }
                    nodes[l, i].value = Squish(newValue + nodes[l, i].bias);

                    //Update test results
                    result.activations[l, i] = nodes[l, i].value; //This value right here is what is causing the issues. Debugging showed that the value is correct (equal to nodes[l, i].value) right after this line, but after the next line the value changes, and it changes again after the next.
                    result.magnitudes[l, i] = newValue;
                    result.biases[l, i] = nodes[l, i].bias;

                    float debug = result.activations[l, i];
                }
            }
```

In short, the value of

```
result.activations[l, i]
```

Should remain equivalent to

```
nodes[l, i].value
```

...but for some reason it just doesn't. If it helps, the value of `nodes[l, i].value` is always between 0 and 1 (debugging shows that this works properly), and yet the value of `result.activations[l, i]` always ends up as a negative integer (a typical value of `result.biases[l, i]`). I tried changing all of the value types to decimal (in this state, they are floats), but the result was the same.

I've destroyed Google's search button to find that nobody has really had this issue before. At this point I'm starting to think it's a bug with visual studio itself. Any help in solving this issue would be appreciated. Restarting both Visual Studio and my laptop did nothing.
Thanks,
Ryan G.

**EDIT:** Here's the full method, including the loop I highlighted previously in this question. Hope this gives a better context.

```
TestResults TestNetwork(byte[] image, int[] nodeCounts, Node[ , ] nodes, int actual)
        {
            float[,] resultsFloats = new float[nodeCounts.Count(), nodes.GetLength(1)];
            TestResults result = new TestResults(0, resultsFloats, resultsFloats, new float[nodeCounts.Count(), nodes.GetLength(1), nodes.GetLength(1)], resultsFloats, 0);

            int finalResult = 0;

            //Match image values to input nodes

            for(int i = 0; i < nodeCounts[0]; i++)
            {
                nodes[0, i].value = (float)image[i] / 255;

                //Update test results
                result.activations[0, i] = nodes[0, i].value;
            }

            //Calculate values for second, third, and fourth layers

            for (int l = 1; l < 4; l++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeCounts[l]; i++)
                {
                    float newValue = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < nodeCounts[l - 1]; j++)
                    {
                        float inputValue = nodes[l - 1, j].value;
                        float newMag = (inputValue * nodes[l, i].weights[j]);

                        newValue += newMag;

                        //Update test results
                        result.weights[l, i, j] = nodes[l, i].weights[j];
                    }
                    nodes[l, i].value = Squish(newValue + nodes[l, i].bias);

                    //Update test results
                    result.activations[l, i] = nodes[l, i].value;
                    result.magnitudes[l, i] = newValue;
                    result.biases[l, i] = nodes[l, i].bias;

                    float debug = result.activations[l, i];
                }
            }
            //Decide result

            float mag = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (nodes[nodeCounts.Count() - 1, i].value > mag)
                {
                    finalResult = i;
                    mag = nodes[nodeCounts.Count() - 1, i].value;
                }
            }

            result.finalResult = finalResult;
            result.actual = actual;

            return result;
        }
```

The Node is just another class I have to hold more data. As you can see at the top of the function, when the instance of TestResults is initialized, memory is allocated for each of the arrays using other values.

**EDIT 2:**
Just ran another test:

```
TestResults dTR = new TestResults(0, new float[2, 2], new float[2, 2], new float[2, 2, 2], new float[2, 2], 0);
            dTR.activations[0, 0] = 1;
            dTR.magnitudes[0, 0] = 2;
            dTR.biases[0, 0] = 3;

            Console.WriteLine(dTR.activations[0, 0] + ", " + dTR.magnitudes[0, 0] + ", " + dTR.biases[0, 0]);
```

This outputs "1, 2, 3" as it should. I don't understand what makes this different from my problematic code.

**UPDATE:** After giving up and wanting to sleep, I realized that the main issue was that `result.activations[l, i]` was being changed since I was changing values after I already changed its own value. So, attempting the obvious, I just put the line where I modify its value after the lines where I modify all of the other values. Worked like a charm.

I see that this is a bit of a duct-tape solution, and I do want to see why this was happening still, so I will update this post later as I try out some of the suggested fixes in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you're not allocating memory for your arrays.

In your constructor you should be allocating memory for your arrays. Something like:

```
public TestResults()
{
    activations = new float[10,10];
    magnitudes = new float[10,10];
    weights = new float[10,10,10];
    biases = new float[10,10];
}
```

In the above code, you allocate 10 "spaces" if you will, for each multi-dimensional array. Otherwise, you're overriding your memory, as it has not been allocated.

Also, the way you have it right now will not work, because the input parameters to your constructor are being passed by value, so if you really want to instantiate them outside of the constructor and pass them in, you need to make them references with the `ref` keyword.

If you want to make your life easier, use lists, and let them grow dynamically as your code might require, without you having to worry about it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey,

The line where I allocate memory to the arrays is actually excluded from the sample of code I gave. I updated the original question with the full method. Is there anything problematic with how I initialize these arrays?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. I would still initialize the arrays in line inside the constructor. Give that a try and see if it changes anything.